# IOS/Objective-C: Detect What is Different About Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays

I have a bug whereby an array of NSNumbers that is dynamically created is not producing the expected results.  To see what is in the array, I have logged it out.  I also manually created an equivalent array that does produce expected results and logged it out.  The elements appear to be identical when logged but when I do an isEqualArray test they are different.  Can anyone suggest a way to detect what is different so that I can fix it?  Thanks for any suggestions.

Here is the code that logs out the arrays:

```
    -(NSMutableDictionary *) getExistingContactsWithUIDs:(NSArray *)uids
{
       int numElements = (int) uids.count; 
        NSLog(@"num elements in uids%d",numElements); //logs as 3
        NSLog(@"first elementzzz%@zzz",uids[0]); //logs as zzz2101zzz
        NSLog(@"2nd elementzzz%@zzz",uids[1]); //logs as zzz2098zzz
        NSLog(@"3rd elementzzz%@zzz",uids[2]);//logs as zzz2100zzz

    //Manually created array
     NSArray*ualtids = @[@2101, @2098, @2100];
        int numElementsAlt = (int) ualtids.count; 
        NSLog(@"num elements in uids%d",numElementsAlt); //logs as 3
        NSLog(@"first alt elementzzz%@zzz",ualtids[0]);//logs as zzz2101zzz
        NSLog(@"2nd alt elementzzz%@zzz",ualtids[1]);//logs as zzz2098zzz
        NSLog(@"3rd alt elementzzz%@zzz",ualtids[2]);//logs as zzz2100zzz
        //code to compare says they are different
        if ([uids isEqualToArray:ualtids]) {
            NSLog(@"Arrays same");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Arrays different ");
        }
    //Finally the code that creates the uids array is:
     NSMutableArray *newUIDs = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (i=0;i<max;i++)
        {
    uid = importContact.cid;  
            [newUIDs addObject:uid];
    }
```

Comment: you're using `uids` and not `ids`, is that on purpose?

Comment: What you want to achieve? Do you want to compare that arrays are equal or not? Or you want the difference also?

Comment: Lots of things can log as "2101". You have not proved that these are both arrays of NSNumber. Maybe one array contains NSNumber and the other contains NSString. Who knows? Your logging is really unrevealing of the details.

Comment: I realize that and that is the question.  The elements log the same but are not.  So, how does one detect how they differ?

Comment: Lion, I want to find out specifically what about uids differs from uialtids gives the desired result but is hard coded.  I want to find out how uids (which is dynamic) differs so that I can modify it to work properly.

Comment: zil,I think that was autocorrect in textbox.  Fixed it.

Comment: "The elements log the same but are not. So, how does one detect how they differ?" You need to log the `class` of the element. For example, `NSLog(@"%@", [uids[0] class])`. Do that for all your elements in both your arrays.

Comment: Even better, just debug. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Voice of ObiWan Kenobi:] Uuuuuuse the debugggerrrrr, Luuuuuuke!

The problem is that you are using the NSLog command. That calls `description` so you don't learn what the class of the NSArray's elements is. An NSNumber wrapping 1 and an NSString `@"1"` log exactly the same. So you learn nothing.

But if you will simply *pause in the debugger* at a breakpoint after the arrays are configured, you can examine them in the variables list, as shown here:

[image]

Those two arrays (`arr1` and `arr2`) *log* the same, but in the variables list it is perfectly plain that one contains NSStrings and the other contains NSNumbers.